# Sci-Kit Learn: Incorporate Naive Bayes Model Predictions into Logistic Regression?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, logistic-regression

I have data on various customer attributes (self-description and age), and a binary outcome of whether these customers would buy a specific product

```
  {"would_buy": "No", 
  "self_description": "I'm a college student studying biology", 
  "Age": 19},
```

**I'd like to use [`MultinomialNB`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) on `self-description` to predict `would_buy`, and then incorporate those predictions into a logistic regression model on `would_buy` that takes also takes `age` as a covariate.**

Code for the text model so far (I am new to SciKit!) with a simplified dataset.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

#Customer data that includes whether a customer would buy an item (what I'm interested), their self-description, and their age. 
data = [
  {"would_buy": "No", "self_description": "I'm a college student studying biology", "Age": 19}, 
  {"would_buy": "Yes", "self_description": "I'm a blue-collar worker", "Age": 20},
  {"would_buy": "No", "self_description": "I'm a Stack Overflow denzien", "Age": 56}, 
  {"would_buy": "No", "self_description": "I'm a college student studying economics", "Age": 20}, 
  {"would_buy": "Yes", "self_description": "I'm a UPS worker", "Age": 35}, 
  {"would_buy": "No", "self_description": "I'm a Stack Overflow denzien", "Age": 56}
  ]

def naive_bayes_model(customer_data):
  self_descriptions = [customer['self_description'] for customer in customer_data]
  decisions = [customer['would_buy'] for customer in customer_data]

  vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,2))
  X = vectorizer.fit_transform(self_descriptions, decisions)
  naive_bayes = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01)
  naive_bayes.fit(X, decisions)
  train(naive_bayes, X, decisions)

def train(classifier, X, y):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=22)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print(classification_report(classifier.predict(X_test), y_test))


def main():
  naive_bayes_model(data)



main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be to use the [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.predict_proba) or [`predict_log_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.predict_log_proba) methods on your trained `naive_bayes` to create the inputs for your logistic regression model. These could be concatenated with the `Age` values to create the training and testing sets for your LogisticRegression model.

However, I do want to point out that the code as you have written does not give you access to your `naive_bayes` model after it is trained. So you definitely need to restructure your code.

That issue aside, this is how I would incorporate the output of `naive_bayes` into a LogisticRegression:

```
descriptions = np.array([customer['self_description'] for customer in data])
decisions = np.array([customer['would_buy'] for customer in data])
ages = np.array([customer['Age'] for customer in data])

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,2))
desc_vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(descriptions, decisions)
naive_bayes = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01)
desc_train, desc_test, age_train, age_test, dec_train, dec_test = train_test_split(desc_vec, ages, decisions, test_size=0.25, random_state=22)

naive_bayes.fit(desc_train, dec_train)
nb_train_preds = naive_bayes.predict_proba(desc_train)
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr_X_train = np.hstack((nb_tarin_preds, age_train.reshape(-1, 1)))
lr.fit(lr_X_train, dec_train)

lr_X_test = np.hstack((naive_bayes.predict_proba(desc_test), age_test.reshape(-1, 1)))
lr.score(lr_X_test, dec_test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment; this is exactly what I was looking for. If I may, what would I do if the additional variable, instead of `age` , was actually categorical (eg: `city` )? Would you suggest using one-hot encoding or making two Naive Bayes classifiers and then multiplying probabilities?

Comment: Always a fan of one hot encoding myself.